# How to copy/paste web content with photos into my blog

Tags: text, images

I use my wordpress blog for research... When I write about something, the firs thing I do is research of what's already out there on given topic. What I want to do is to be able to copy paste parts of the web pages for reference... If the page is only text... that's grand. But If the page contains pictures, I can't copy that image to my research blog easily... is there a plugin which would allow me to copy parts of webpages (with pictures) into my blog - same as I was using microsoft word for note taking.

Thanks

Edit:
Actually I need something which will enable me to use my wordpress as evernote... I want to store content on my blog and be able to access it later... Easily

Comment: I think you should try this plugin, http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cache-images/ have a nice day! ;)

Comment: or this http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/image-elevator/ that allows to copy and paste images

Answer (score 4):

A little tip a lot of people don't know about. You can copy/paste an image url into the upload field and it will be auto uploaded into your blog.

Right click the image you want to save and select copy image URL (chrome)

In your blog click Add Image--> Select Files ( from computer)-->paste url into the upload dialog where it says "file name".

This works on windows not sure if does on other OS's.

Answer (score 2):

Hot-linking images is bad form, which means that you need to attach images to your post. So, copy/paste really won't work. You just need to save the image, and then upload it to you post.

Comment: Nice. Thanks... but still... simple copy/paste style like in MS word is something a lot of people would appreciate.... I actually don't want hot-linking.. something which will will do the download img / upload img automatically for me.... for all images in the clipboard...

Answer (score 0):

A simple copy paste of the source will include the images but hot linking is something you should always avoid.

Comment: I actually don't want hot-linking.. something which will will do the download img / upload img automatically for me.... for all images in the clipboard...